# Write a program to read two numbers, the first less than the second. The program will write all numbers between the two numbers

Tags: java, while-loop, counter, jgrasp

//So I wrote this: (the output down there)

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class E7L6{
public static void main(String[]args){
int num1, num2;
Scanner keyboard= new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Type two numbers:");
num1= keyboard.nextInt();
num2= keyboard.nextInt();

if(num1<num2){
   while(num1<=num2){
   int counter=num1;
   System.out.print(counter+" "+num2);
   counter=counter+1;
   }}
else{
   System.out.print("Error: the first number must be smaller than the second");
}   
  }}

Output:
 ----jGRASP exec: java E7L6
Type two numbers:4 124
 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4
 ----jGRASP: process ended by user.
```

//so many number 4 repeating can someone tell me where am i wrong? thanks!!

Comment: Same problem -- all you're doing is begging for an answer. Sheesh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  while(num1<=num2){
   int counter=num1;
   System.out.print(counter+" "+num2);
   counter=counter+1;
  }
```

This will end up in infinite loop. The condition for the while loop needs to be modified.

// modified code - Complete code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class E7L6 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int num1, num2;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Type two numbers:");
        num1 = keyboard.nextInt();
        num2 = keyboard.nextInt();

        if (num1 < num2) {
            int counter = num1;
            while (counter <= num2) {
                System.out.print(counter + " ");
                counter = counter + 1;
            }
        } else {
            System.out
                    .print("Error: the first number must be smaller than the second");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks! i have a sequence of numbers now, but it's not limited to num2 (example 4 10) it doesn't stop at 10

Comment: I have updated the complete code here. Its working for me. Just compare with your code.

Comment: @GreenShadow: Please don't do people's homework for them.  Instead, explain what the problem is and let them figure out how to solve it on their own.  Otherwise, you defeat the purpose of homework.

Comment: @GreenShadow: yep, he just deleted his most recent question, but all you've taught him, it seems is how to beg.

Answer (score 4):

```
int counter=num1;
```

You created a new `counter` variable for each iteration of the loop.
Therefore, they all have the same value.

It runs forever because your loop condition can never be false (you never change `num1` or `num2`).

Comment: I modified it to put the int counter first, and i have now a sequence of numbers but still running forever, (1 10) doesn't stop at 10 it continues over it?

Comment: @BaderK: As I said at the end of my answer, you need to change your loop so that it knows when to stop.

Answer (score 0):

As a novice programmer I would use for loop instead. It would be simpler and easier:

```
for(ctr=num1;ctr<=num2;ctr++)
   s.o.p(ctr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
System.out.print("First:");
    int first = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());
    System.out.print("Second:");
    int second = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());
    while (first <= second) {
        System.out.println(first);
        first++;
    }
```